# Слово "дупа" - літературне?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники, ненормативна-лексика

Натрапила на статтю ["Чи можна дорослих бити по дупі"](https://life.pravda.com.ua/columns/2018/05/21/231045/), в якій вжито слово "***дупа***".

Також знайшла в [Орфографічному словнику](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0) це слово із зазначенням:

> **дупа** - іменник, жіночий рід, неістота, однина і множина.

Однак [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/dupa) його все ж не подає.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [Словнику українського сленгу](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53396/374372.html) знаходимо:

> **ДУПА** 
>   (-и) ж. мол. 
>   1. Зад. Мене розважив задушливий декор серпасто-молоткастих кумачів<...>, а особливо офіціянтка з діркою на джинсовій дупі (Смолоскипи, 1997, № 2).
>   ■ Від польськ. згруб. dupa - задниця.

В [Тлумачному словнику української мови](https://eslovnyk.com/%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0) також знаходимо це слово із позначкою зах.:

> **дупа**
>   -и, ж., зах.
>   Сідниця.

Отже, це слово – діалектизм.

Answer (score 2):

Якщо заглянути у С[ловник українських жаргонізмів](http://ukr-zhargon.wikidot.com/synonimy), то бачимо, що слово "дупа" буде жаргоном-синонімом до слів "зад" та "сідниці". Також, згідно до [цієї](http://ipress.ua/ljlive/matyuky_yaki_roblyat_z_tebe_ukraintsya_yak_pravylno_layatys_7348.html), [цієї](https://inlviv.in.ua/suspilstvo/kultura/yakshho-nabrydly-matyuky-yak-pravylno-layatysya-ukrayinskoyu) та [цієї](https://prolviv.com/blog/2018/02/07/laimosia-po-lvivsky/) статей, бачимо, що слово "дупа" - це лайка, а крім того ще й галицизм. Цитата з останньої статті:

> Найпопулярнішими словечками у лайці львівського балаку були фрази
>   саме, з використанням таких слів, як “г@вно”, “с@ака”, “дупа”.

Отож, без жодних сумнівів можемо зробити висновок, що слово це краще не вживати у літературних творах. А саме воно є галицизмом і жаргонізмом.